# JSF DataTable not displaying database

Tags: java, jsf

I came across a method in which I could display the data in my database on the website. However, I followed an example that I had, which was to create a bean, create a datatable on the page I want to display but when I run the website, it only prints out the string of the beans. How do I correct this?

**index.xhtml**

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{addressBean.addresses}" var="address" rowClasses="oddRows,evenRows" headerClass="header" styleClass="table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">First Name</f:facet>
    #{address.FIRSTNAME}
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Last Name</f:facet>
    #{address.LASTNAME}
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Street</f:facet>
    #{address.STREET}
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">City</f:facet>
    #{address.CITY}
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">State</f:facet>
    #{address.STATE}
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Zip code</f:facet>
    #{address.ZIP}
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

**AddressBean.java**

```js
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;

@
ManagedBean(name = "addressBean")
public class AddressBean {
  // instance variables that represent one address
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String street;
  private String city;
  private String state;
  private String zipcode;

  // allow the server to inject the DataSource
  @
  Resource(name = "jdbc/addressbook")
  DataSource dataSource;

  // get the first name
  public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
    } // end method getFirstName

  // set the first name
  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
    } // end method setFirstName

  // get the last name
  public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
    } // end method getLastName

  // set the last name
  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
    } // end method setLastName

  // get the street
  public String getStreet() {
      return street;
    } // end method getStreet

  // set the street
  public void setStreet(String street) {
      this.street = street;
    } // end method setStreet

  // get the city
  public String getCity() {
      return city;
    } // end method getCity

  // set the city
  public void setCity(String city) {
      this.city = city;
    } // end method setCity

  // get the state
  public String getState() {
      return state;
    } // end method getState

  // set the state
  public void setState(String state) {
      this.state = state;
    } // end method setState

  // get the zipcode
  public String getZipcode() {
      return zipcode;
    } // end method getZipcode

  // set the zipcode
  public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
      this.zipcode = zipcode;
    } // end method setZipcode

  // save a new address book entry
  public String save() throws SQLException {
      // check whether dataSource was injected by the server
      if (dataSource == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to obtain DataSource");

      // obtain a connection from the connection pool
      Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

      // check whether connection was successful
      if (connection == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to connect to DataSource");

      try {
        // create a PreparedStatement to insert a new address book entry
        PreparedStatement addEntry =
          connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ADDRESSES " +
            "(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,STREET,CITY,STATE,ZIP)" +
            "VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )");

        // specify the PreparedStatement's arguments
        addEntry.setString(1, getFirstName());
        addEntry.setString(2, getLastName());
        addEntry.setString(3, getStreet());
        addEntry.setString(4, getCity());
        addEntry.setString(5, getState());
        addEntry.setString(6, getZipcode());

        addEntry.executeUpdate(); // insert the entry
        return "index"; // go back to index.xhtml page
      } // end try
      finally {
        connection.close(); // return this connection to pool
      } // end finally
    } // end method save

  // return a ResultSet of entries
  public ResultSet getAddresses() throws SQLException {
      // check whether dataSource was injected by the server
      if (dataSource == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to obtain DataSource");

      // obtain a connection from the connection pool
      Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

      // check whether connection was successful
      if (connection == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to connect to DataSource");

      try {
        // create a PreparedStatement to insert a new address book entry
        PreparedStatement getAddresses = connection.prepareStatement(
          "SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, STREET, CITY, STATE, ZIP " +
          "FROM ADDRESSES ORDER BY LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME");

        CachedRowSet rowSet = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();
        rowSet.populate(getAddresses.executeQuery());
        return rowSet;
      } // end try
      finally {
        connection.close(); // return this connection to pool
      } // end finally
    } // end method getAddresses
} // end class AddressBean
```

**Database SQL**

```html
DROP TABLE Addresses;

CREATE TABLE Addresses
(
 AddressID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
 FirstName VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 LastName VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 Street VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
 City VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 State VARCHAR (2) NOT NULL,
 Zip VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (AddressID)
);

INSERT INTO Addresses (FirstName,LastName,Street,City,State,Zip) VALUES 
   ('Bob','Green','5 Bay St.','San Francisco','CA','94133'),
   ('Liz','White','100 5th Ave.','New York','NY','10011'),
   ('Mike','Brown','3600 Delmar Blvd.','St. Louis','MO','63108'),
   ('Mary','Green','300 Massachusetts Ave.','Boston','MA','02115'),
   ('John','Gray','500 South St.','Philadelphia','PA','19147'),
   ('Meg','Gold','1200 Stout St.','Denver','CO','80204'),
   ('James','Blue','1000 Harbor Ave.','Seattle','WA','98116'),
   ('Sue','Black','1000 Michigan Ave.','Chicago','IL','60605');
```

Answer (score 0):

First off I would create a new managed bean which is possibly `@ViewScoped` which has a list of `AddressBean` objects (dont forget getter/setter):

```
private ArrayList <AddressBean> addresses = new ArrayList <AddressBean>();
```

Then I would move your `getAddresses()` method to this new bean and change it so that it iterates through the `ResultSet` of your query, creating `AddressBean` objects and then adding them to the addresses `ArrayList`. I would then make a call to this `getAddresses()` method in the constructor of the new "View Bean" so that the addresses from the database are loaded when the bean is instantiated.

NOTE: So have one `AddressBean` managed bean with getters/setters and then another "View Bean" which calls the method to load up the database records and stores `AddressBean` objects in an `ArrayList`. As well as this look into structuring your project using layers of intergration between the database, java and web levels (Data Access Layer, Business Layer and UI bean layer etc etc).

Your datatable in the xhtml will then chage from:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{addressBean.addresses}" var="address" rowClasses="oddRows,evenRows" headerClass="header" styleClass="table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
```

To:

```
<h:dataTable value="**#{addressViewBean.addresses}**" var="address" rowClasses="oddRows,evenRows" headerClass="header" styleClass="table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
```

**EDIT: In response to your comment you could do something like this:**

Declare an AddressBean object with getters/setters at the top of the afore mentioned "View bean":

```
private AddressBean addressBean;
```

Then in your view bean method which connects to the database and loads the records, do something like this....

```
while(rowSet.next())
{
    addressBean= new AddressBean(rowSet.getString("FirstName"), rowSet.getString("LastName"), rowSet.getString("Street"), rowSet.getString("City"), rowSet.getString("State"), rowSet.getString(("Zip"));
    addresses.add(addressBean);
}
```

place the above code after

```
 rowSet.populate(getAddresses.executeQuery());
```

and change the return type to void.

Comment: Ok. The problem I'm having trouble understanding is loading the records from the database and saving it to an arraylist. Can you simplify it please?